# MySQL multiple-column indexes on username, password

Tags: mysql, database-indexes

In a MySQL database I have to maintain I have this table with two indexes

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,

    -- some attributes

    nickname VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,

    -- other attributes

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX auth (nickname, password),
    INDEX region_id (region)
);
```

My question is about `auth` index. It is a multi-column index, but since `nickname` is `UNIQUE`, isn't `password` somehow redundant? Why an index on both `nickname` and `password`? Why not only `nickname` since it is `UNIQUE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having this two-column index mysql can run queries for authentication checking(ones that do not select data, only `id` or `count(id)` by username and password) without actually accessing data in table, only by index itself, which is the fastest

Comment: I know that. The real question is: «why an index on `nickname` *and* `password`? Why not only on `nickname` since it is `UNIQUE`?»

Comment: Because if password is not in index - to check it mysql will have to find record's id via index, and then go search for record itself in table by id and only then have the answer

Comment: Ok, now I probably understand. If the index contains `password` then the table is never accessed during a "login query" because we already have all the information in the index, right? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Index is only needed when you want to search through index field.

I think it is better to create index of nickname field only if it is already unique one.

But make sure that you always use nickname field in the where clause or joins at first before password field.

e.g. where nickname = 'somevalue' and password = 'somepassword'. This will accelerate query and reduce query result fetching time.

Comment: Thank you. But the precise question is: does an index on `nickname` and `password` attributes behaves exactly like an index only on `nickname`? I read the MySQL documentation on indexes and multiple-column indexes and couldn't find the answer to this precise question.

Comment: Well, creating index on nickname only and nickname + password won't create much difference here if you use the nickname first in the where query as shown above.

You can run the same query with single index first and note the time
now create cumulative index of both fields and run the same query again and note the time.

Now see the time difference! You should either go for single or cumulative which gives less time to fetch data from db.

Comment: Alpesh Panchal it wil cause bigger delay  because the query has to acces actual table to carry out comparisons.